# Default Date set to yesterday in DATE prompt in COGNOS 11.0.6

Tags: cognos

I have tried the below java script code but it's not working in COGNOS 11.

```
<script language="javascript">
  var dDate = new Date();
  dDate.setDate(dDate.getDate()-1);
  pickerControlName.setValue(getFormatDate(dDate, 0 , 'YMD'));
</script>
```

Is there any other way I can set it to default ??

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the Cognos Prompt API. You can see a tutorial on how to do what you want with the API here: [Setting Prompt Defaults Dynamically](http://cogblogger.com/2015/02/javascript-setting-prompt-defaults-dynamically/)

Comment: Do you mean Cognos Java Script API ? In Cognos 11 , we can add java script code but using custom control and for custom control we have to give the file path which will have the java script code. Unfortunately I do not have access to the server where I can save the file.

Comment: It's my understanding that the API is still available in Cognos 11. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEP7J_11.0.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_cr_rptstd.doc/c_prmpt_api_overview.html

Answer (score 0):

I have tried achieving this with JS however I would recommend using the base cognos filter screen.Try the following.

1) Assign a parameter name to the date prompt **'DATE_FILTER'**. So on Query explorer-Detail Filters you would do **cast(YOUR_DATE_FIELD,date) = ?DATE_FILTER?**. 
NOTE - Make Usage optional.

2) Now create 2 data item named **'START_DATE'** AND **'END_DATE'**. 
START_DATE expression :
**case when #prompt('DATE_FILTER','date','null')# = null then cast(_add_days(current_date,-1),date) else cast(_add_days(current_date,-30000),date)   end**

END_DATE expression :
**case when #prompt('DATE_FILTER','date','null')# = null then cast(_add_days(current_date,-1),date) else cast(_add_days(current_date,30000),date)   end**

3) Then add below to Summary filter expression :

**cast([YOUR_DATE_FIELD],date) between [START_DATE] and [END_DATE]**

This should create effect similar to 
**GROUP BY YOUR_DATE_FIELD 
HAVING TRUNC(YOUR_DATE_FIELD) = SYSDATE-1** 
when parameter **'DATE_FILTER'** is null.

You could also achieve this by directly inserting #prompt()# clause into the Manual SQL.

Comment: I created a date prompt using a date column in my report,I am not sure how to do STEP 1 and can you also tell me how to add data item , because I added the data items using framework management

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Cognos javascript and needed to dynamically set a Date prompt. I found a way to do it.

If you change your code to look something like this:

```
var dDate = new Date();
dDate.setDate(dDate.getDate()-1);
var pickerControlObject = oPage.getControlByName( "pickerControlName" );
pickerControlObject.setValues([{use: dDate.toISOString().slice(0,10)}]);
```

This worked for me in Cognos 11. I was using the '.js module' method not the 'HTML item' method